# Losing privilege with points lost in setting bounties

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

Is it appropriate for users to lose privileges with handing out bounties? I've recently posted a bounty worth 400 points and consequently lost even the simple privilege of commenting everywhere. I think this drawback is uncalled for, and suggest that privileges are unaffected by points lost with bounties.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it has always worked.

If there were no cost to a bounty, then everyone would post one, and they would lose part of their essential value as motivators.

Comment: But if privileges signify the trust of community in a user, why would posting bounties reduce the trust the community places in the user?

Comment: @Oxwivi I see it more as, "I want an answer to this question so badly I am willing to give up this privilege in exchange." That said, I would definitely advise users to avoid going below 100 reputation. http://askubuntu.com/privileges

Comment: I don't know - even if someone wants answers bad enough to give up privileges, there should be a limit to how much privileges one can lose...

Comment: I think that it should be as such: You don't lose your current privileges, but you are farther from new ones.